# Remove product in the cart using ajax in woocommerce

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to remove the product in the woocommerce cart using ajax without click the  link.

If you have encounter this kind of functionality, please help us.

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'add_js_to_wp_wcommerce');

function add_js_to_wp_wcommerce(){ ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('.remove-product').click(function(){
        var product_id = jQuery(this).attr("data-product_id");
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            data: { action: "product_remove", 
                    product_id: product_id
            },success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
    </script>
<?php }

add_action( 'wp_ajax_product_remove', 'product_remove' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_product_remove', 'product_remove' );
function product_remove() {
    global $wpdb, $woocommerce;
    session_start();
    foreach ($woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item){
        if($cart_item['product_id'] == $_POST['product_id'] ){
            // Remove product in the cart using  cart_item_key.
            $woocommerce->cart->get_remove_url($cart_item_key);
        }
    }
    print_r($woocommerce->cart->get_cart());
    //echo json_encode(array('status' => 0));
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 23):

you could use the WC_Cart `set_quantity` method

And do as this in your php:

```
$cart = WC()->instance()->cart;
$id = $_POST['product_id'];
$cart_id = $cart->generate_cart_id($id);
$cart_item_id = $cart->find_product_in_cart($cart_id);

if($cart_item_id){
   $cart->set_quantity($cart_item_id,0);
}
```

Comment: Just note, that this code won't work for a variable product. In this case you will ether have to add the `$variation_id` to the function `generate_cart_id()` or you pass the `$cart_id` (actually it's correctly called `$cart_item_key` from the ajax script already.

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work for a variable product. I've passed along my variation ID as a parameter in generate_cart_id, as the docs state, but nothing happens. Am I forgetting something?

Comment: Can you please clear here where to put this function ?

Comment: You should add that code in the php called in ajax. 

I must say that I'm not sure this still works with recent versions of woo commerce

Comment: Anyone could implement this to variable product? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39286294/remove-variable-product-from-cart-with-ajax-in-woocommerce

Answer (score 6):

use this :

```
$cart = $woocommerce->cart;

foreach ($woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item){
    if($cart_item['product_id'] == $_POST['product_id'] ){
        // Remove product in the cart using  cart_item_key.
        $cart->remove_cart_item($cart_item_key);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one :

```
foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

 if($cart_item['product_id'] == $product_id){

  unset($cartdetails->cart_contents[$cart_item_key]);

 }
}
```